# parallel file copy using tee unexpectedly slow

Tags: ssh, remote, file-copy, tee

we're copying a large zfs snapshot (zfs send) from site-1 to site-2. site-1 and site-2 are remote, and are connected via IPsec (read: slow)

on site-2, we need the data on two different zfs servers. currently we're using two simultaneous ssh "zfs send" | zfs receive commands. this is of course a waste of bandwidth.

we've experimented with the following (1 remote ssh, tee, 1 local ssh):

```
[root@site-2-1 ~]# \
    time \
    ssh root@site-1-0 \
        "cat /tmp/100000000.rnd | pigz -1" \
    | pv -B 10m -s 100000000 \
    | tee \
        >(ssh root@site-2-2 "pigz -d > /tmp/test.rnd.1") \
    | pigz -d \
    > /tmp/test.rnd.1

95.4MiB 0:00:52 [1.83MiB/s] [===<snipped>===>] 100%

real    0m52.062s
user    0m0.979s
sys 0m1.100s
```

which turned out to be slower than a simulation of the original solution (2 remote ssh's simultaneously):

```
[root@site-2-1 ~]# \
    time \
    ssh root@site-1-0 \
        "cat /tmp/100000000.rnd | pigz -1" \
    | pv -B 10m -s 100000000 \
    | pigz -d \
    > /tmp/test.rnd.2
95.4MiB 0:00:30 [3.09MiB/s] [===<snipped>===>] 100%

real    0m30.837s
user    0m0.827s
sys 0m1.003s


[root@site-2-2 ~]# \
    time \
    ssh root@site-1-0 \
        "cat /tmp/100000000.rnd | pigz -1" \
    | pv -B 10m -s 100000000 \
    | pigz -d \
    > /tmp/test.rnd.2
95.4MiB 0:00:38 [ 2.5MiB/s] [===<snipped>===>] 100%

real    0m38.187s
user    0m0.840s
sys 0m0.846s
```

we've looked into tee's code, our prime suspect, and it seems it operates out of a single thread.

can anyone recomment a faster alternative to tee, or a totally different solution maybe?

thanks in advance,
guven

Answer (score 1):

suggestion:

```
zfs send > file
scp file server-at-site2:
ssh server-at-site2 zfs receive < file
ssh server-at-site2 cat file | ssh second-server-at-site2 zfs receive
```

That requires two transfers, but presumably the second will be faster (because local network, etc)

Comment: our file is huge as well (> 1TB) so we'd need another storage for that

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that :-) How about receiving it on the first server, and then sending it again from that server to the second one? That might take a little longer depending on the speed of your ZFS, but at least you don't need the extra storage and waste less bandwidth. And since a ZFS receive requires that the start snapshot is present and creates (at least) the end snapshot, this doesn't require extra snapshots of something.

Comment: that is one of our last resort options, if all else fails :)